dbt_rpc v0.3.3 cannot process the "list" command
Is there support for the list command in rpc?
dbt_core v1.4.9
dbt_sql_adapter v1.4.3
dbt_rpc 0.3.3
my query:
'{'
'"jsonrpc": "2.0",'
'"method": "cli_args",'
'"id": "b69575e2-b1db-463b-a725-8ba200afea85",'
'"params": {'
'"cli": "ls"'
'}}'

Server response:
{'error': {'code': -32000, 'message': 'Server error', 'data': {'type': 'DbtInternalError', 'args': ['No matching handler found for rpc method None (which=list)'], 'message': 'Internal Error\n No matching handler found for rpc method None (which=list)'}}, 'id': 'b69575e2-b1db-463b-a725-8ba200afea85', 'jsonrpc': '2.0'}

Similar error for request:
'{'
'"jsonrpc": "2.0",'
'"method": "ls",'
'"id": "b69575e2-b1db-463b-a725-8ba200afea85",'
'"params": {'
'"select": "{MODEL_FOLDER}"'
'}}'

Server response:
{'error': {'code': -32601, 'message': 'Method not found'}, 'id': 'b69575e2-b1db-463b-a725-8ba200afea85', 'jsonrpc': '2.0'}

